# Planes vs a plane

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, indefinite-article

If I say

1. I took a plane to Canada.

I believe it means I took one certain plane.

But

2. I took planes to Canada.

Does it mean that I was in some planes at once? 
And not mean "I took a plane and I changed planes"?

Should I say "I took a plane and  changed planes to Canada."?

Comment: It means you took one many plane at once, but it also means you took more than one plane but not at once. It depends on the listener understanding. And of course, you cannot take more than one plane at once.

Comment: *'I took a connecting flight to Canada'*

Answer (score 1):

> I took a plane to Canada
>   I travelled by plane to Canada.

Most people would understand both of these expressions as specifying a means of transport, rather than specifying that you did the entire journey on one go.

If you really need to tell the listener how many stages were involved in your journey, you can say

> One flight:
>   I took a direct flight to Canada - *one flight*
>
> Two flights:
>   I travelled by plane to Canada, with a connection in New York.
>   My flight to Canada was in two legs.
>
> Three flights:
>   I travelled by plane to Canada, with connections in London and New York.
>   My flight to Canada was in three legs.
>
> Etc...

In this context, a [leg](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leg) means **a particular stage of a journey, competition, or activity**.

If your stay at one of the intermediate locations is more than a few hours, you can refer to it as a [stopover](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stopover) or a [layover](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/layover).

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using the word plane, I would use "flight". And in case you travel on several of them consecutively, you could say you have taken several connecting flights to Canada.

So your sentences are:

1. I took a flight to Canada.
2. I took a connecting flight to Canada. (for a single stopover)
3. I took multiple connecting flights to Canada. ( for multiple stopovers)

In case you want to stick to the word plane, you could say something like:

1. I took (was on) a plane to Canada.

For connecting flights, it's not correct to say planes(plural), as you are not travelling on multiple ones at the same time. 
But you could say something like

> I took multiple planes to arrive in Canada.

Comment: "Plane" is a shortened form of "airplane".  **Flights** may be the better choice here, but "plane" is perfectly acceptable, at least in AmE. *How did you get out to Chicago? --We went by plane.  Was it a direct flight? --No, we took a connecting flight in Houston.*

Comment: I have edited my answer.Thanks for pointing the mistake.